# JFrame Wont Open when Combined with Other Classes in Main

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe

When I instantiate the class that is supposed to open JFrame in the main method that contains another instantiated class, JFrame does not open, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong since there are no syntax erorrs.

Thanks for the help.

Tega

Get Data Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
 * This class get the data from the user in a .csv format and split it into data and variable.
 * The class also turn the level data into returns 
 */

/**
 * @author 
 */

public class GetData 
{
    private ArrayList<String> originalDataString = new  ArrayList<String>();  //This would be used to get the data from file
    private String dateTitle;                                                 //For date title 
    private String variableTitle;                                             //For the title of the variable from your file. 
    private ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();                 //To store the date
    private ArrayList<Double> variableLevel = new ArrayList<Double>();        //To store the content of the Level data
    private ArrayList<Double> variableReturn = new ArrayList<Double>();       //To store the content of the Return data

    /**
     * The constructor opens a file to read the data
     * @param filename The file to open
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public void getDataMethod() throws IOException 
    {
        String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the name of the file you for the data?" +
                                                      "\nThe file must be saved as .csv(comma delimited)");
        File file = new File(filename);

        //Making sure that the file entered exist
        if (!file.exists())
        {
                System.out.println("The file " + filename + " is not found");
                System.exit(0);         
        }


        //Getting the data from the file            
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);  
        String line;  //To read the lines from the data 

        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            line = inputFile.nextLine();            
            //Add each line to the ArrayList
            originalDataString.add(line);       
        }


        //This part split the date and the variable and put them into one array
        String arrayLine = " ";            // To add all the Strings in the originalDataString array. 
        String[] splitOriginalDataString;  // This array stores the split data  

        for (int i = 0; i < originalDataString.size(); i++)
        {
            arrayLine += (originalDataString.get(i) + ",");             
        }

        splitOriginalDataString = arrayLine.split(",");


        //This part separates the data to dates and variable 
        dateTitle = splitOriginalDataString[0];
        variableTitle = splitOriginalDataString[1];                     
        for (int i = 2; i < splitOriginalDataString.length; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
                date.add(splitOriginalDataString[i]);           
            else
                variableLevel.add(Double.parseDouble(splitOriginalDataString[i]));              
        }


        //Getting the returns from the level data
        variableReturn.add(0.0);       //To account for the fact that the returns starts on the second month
        for (int i = 0; i < variableLevel.size()-1; i++)
        {
            variableReturn.add(((variableLevel.get(i+1)/variableLevel.get(i))-1)*100);          
        }       

        // To ask the user if they want to check whether the Level data was imported correctly
        String checkLevelData = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to Check whether the data was imported correctly?" +
                                                      "\n" + "Choose: Y for Yes and N for No"); 

        StringBuilder level = new StringBuilder(); 
        level.append(dateTitle + "       " + variableTitle);
        level.append("\n" + "============");
        for(int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++)
        {
            level.append("\n" + date.get(i) + "          " + variableLevel.get(i));         
        }

        if (checkLevelData.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, level); 
        }


        // To ask the user if they want to check whether the Level data was imported correctly
        String checkReturnData = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to check the return data?" +
                                                              "\n" + "Choose: Y for Yes and N for No"); 

        StringBuilder Lreturn = new StringBuilder(); 
        Lreturn.append(dateTitle + "       " + variableTitle);
        Lreturn.append("\n" + "============");
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        for(int i = 1; i < date.size(); i++)
        {
            Lreturn.append("\n" + date.get(i) + "          " + formatter.format(variableReturn.get(i)));            
        }

        if (checkReturnData.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Lreturn);   
        }


        // Close the file
        inputFile.close();  
        //Exiting the Message Dialog
        System.exit(0); 
    }

    public String getVariableTitle() 
    {
        return variableTitle;
    }

    public String getDateTitle() 
    {
        return dateTitle;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDate()
    {
        return date;        
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getVariableLevel()
    {
        return variableLevel;       
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getVariableReturn()
    {
        return variableReturn;      
    }

}
```

SummaryStatistics Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


/**
 * This class performs some summary statistics of the data. 
 */

/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class SummaryStatistics extends JFrame 
{
    private String dateTitle;                                                 //For date title 
    private String variableTitle;                                             //For the title of the variable from your file. 
    private String[] date;                                                    //To store the date from GetData Class
    private double[] variableLevel;                                           //To store the content of the Level data from GetData Class
    private double[] variableReturn;                                          //To store the content of the Return data from GetData Class
    private JPanel panel;                                                     //To reference a panel
    private JLabel messageLabel;                                              //To reference a label
    private JButton avgLevelButton;
    private JButton lowLevelButton;
    private JButton highLevelButton;
    private JButton varLevelButton;
    private JButton sdLevelButton;
    private JButton allLevelButton;
    private JButton avgReturnButton;
    private JButton lowReturnButton;
    private JButton largeReturnButton;
    private JButton varReturnButton;
    private JButton sdReturnButton;
    private JButton allReturnButton;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 600;                                     //Window width
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGTH = 200;                                    //Window height 


    //Constructor   
    public SummaryStatistics()
    {
        copyGetData();

        //Set the window title
        setTitle("Summary Statistics of " + variableTitle);
        //set the size of the window
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGTH);
        //Specify what happens when the close button is clicked
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Adding the buildPanel method to the frame
        buildPanel();

        //Adding the panel to the frame's content pane
        add(panel);     

        setVisible(true);       
    }

    /**
     * This method copies the data and the data from the GetData Class 
     */
    public void copyGetData()
    {
        GetData data = new GetData();

        //Get the dateTitle and variableTitle
        dateTitle = data.getDateTitle();
        variableTitle = data.getVariableTitle();

        //Copy the date, varibaleLevel and variableReturn 
        date = new String[data.getDate().size()];
        variableLevel = new double[data.getVariableLevel().size()];
        variableReturn = new double[data.getVariableReturn().size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.getDate().size(); i++)
        {
            date[i] = data.getDate().get(i);        
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.getVariableLevel().size(); i++)
        {
            variableLevel[i] = data.getVariableLevel().get(i);      
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.getVariableReturn().size(); i++)
        {
            variableReturn[i] = data.getVariableReturn().get(i);        
        }           
    }

    /**
     * This buildPanel method adds label and a buttons panel. 
     */
    private void buildPanel()
    {
        //Create label to display instructions 
        messageLabel = new JLabel("Press the buttom to get the summary statistics you want");

        //Create the buttons to get the level summary statistics. 
        avgLevelButton = new JButton("Average of the Prices");
        lowLevelButton = new JButton("Lowest Price");
        highLevelButton = new JButton("Highest Price");
        varLevelButton = new JButton("Variance of the Prices");
        sdLevelButton = new JButton("Standard Deviation of the Prices");
        allLevelButton = new JButton("All the Summary Statistics");

        //Adding an action listener to the button
        avgLevelButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());



        //Create a panel object
        panel = new JPanel();
        //Add label and buttons to the panel
        panel.add(messageLabel);
        panel.add(avgLevelButton);
        panel.add(lowLevelButton);
        panel.add(highLevelButton);
        panel.add(varLevelButton);
        panel.add(sdLevelButton);
        panel.add(allLevelButton);
    }

    /**
     * Private inner class that handles the event when the user clicks a button
     */
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Get the action command 
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

            //To create the display format
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

            //Determine which button was clicked

            //Level Statistics
            if (actionCommand.equals("Average of the Prices"));
            {
                double sum = 0;          //Accumulator to get the sum of the data for the average
                for (int i = 0; i < variableLevel.length; i++)
                {
                    sum += variableLevel[i];
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average of the prices of " + variableTitle + ":" +
                                               "\n" + formatter.format(sum/variableLevel.length)); 
            }           
        }       
    }

    //TODO System.exit(0);      

}
```

Main Method:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class AnalyticsDemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //Creating an Instance to GetData class 
        GetData getData = new GetData();
        getData.getDataMethod();

        //Creating an Instance of SummaryStatistics Class
        SummaryStatistics summary = new SummaryStatistics();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I have not yet tried to debug. I try it now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `System.exit(0)` statement at the end of your `getDataMethod` method which will cause the JVM to exit before you even create your frame...

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem.